# Cannot use Menu on my Iiyama Prolite E2480HS?

Tags: display

Just bought a Iiyama Prolite E2480HS monitor. If I press the Menu button I get the menu but then the only change I can get is repressing the Menu button and Contrast (top and automatically chosen) cycles through purple and green but I cannot choose anything. The + and - dont seem to work. Can anyone help please?
I was able to increase the volume from the factory position to 100% but now I can't change that either???

Answer (score -1):

Friend has just helped me. I did not recognise the + and - were the same as the volume and Eco knobs whereas I had been using keyboard + and -. Now all works well.